# JsonRequester Library Access Listener from Inside Function

Tags: android, json, listener, android-volley

I am playing with the [JsonRequester Library](https://github.com/alirezaafkar/JsonRequester) that uses volley to get JSON data from URLS.

My question is, how can I return the JSONObject from the onResponse listener from inside the getJson function?

Here is my JsonHelpers Class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.alirezaafkar.json.requester.interfaces.Methods;
import com.alirezaafkar.json.requester.interfaces.Response;
import com.alirezaafkar.json.requester.requesters.JsonObjectRequester;
import com.alirezaafkar.json.requester.requesters.RequestBuilder;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONHelper {

    public static int USER_REQUEST = 0;

    public JSONObject getJson(Context context, String url){

        JsonObjectRequester mUserRequester;




        JsonObjectListener objectListener = new JsonObjectListener();

        mUserRequester = new RequestBuilder(context)
                .requestCode(USER_REQUEST)
                .showError(true)
                .buildObjectRequester(objectListener);

        mUserRequester.request(Methods.GET, url);


    }

    private class JsonObjectListener extends Response.SimpleObjectResponse {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(int requestCode, @Nullable JSONObject jsonObject) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(int requestCode, VolleyError volleyError, @Nullable JSONObject errorObject) {
            //Error (Not server or network error)
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinishResponse(int requestCode, VolleyError volleyError, String message) {
            //Network or Server error
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestStart(int requestCode) {
            //Show loading or disable button
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestFinish(int requestCode) {
            //Hide loading or enable button
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need it, if you call `getJson()`, that will go in the right `Callback` function. So just do what you want with your response in `onResponse`.

Comment: It is giving me an error that getJson needs a `return`.  Would I just return the `objectListener`?  This is how I am trying to call it from my main activity:

`JSONObject response = JSONHelper.getJson(this, url);`

Comment: Don't return the JsonObject, just do what you want with it in the onResponse. It's the roll of the callback. Where do you need the JsonObject ?

Comment: I was trying to make a generic function that allows me to make a request to a URL and have it returned as a JSONObject to be manipulated however I need.

Comment: You try to make your own Callback. I will give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Callback***

```
public interface Callback {
    public void onResponse(JsonObject jsonObject);
}
```

***Your Class when you need the `JsonObject`***

```
getJson(this, url, new Callback(){
    public void onResponse(JsonObject jsonObject){
         // Do what you want here
}
});
```

***GetJson***

```
public void getJson(Context context, String url, Callback callBack){
        JsonObjectRequester mUserRequester;
        JsonObjectListener objectListener = new JsonObjectListener();

        mUserRequester = new RequestBuilder(context)
                .requestCode(USER_REQUEST)
                .showError(true)
                .buildObjectRequester(objectListener);

        mUserRequester.request(Methods.GET, url);
    }
```

***JsonObjectListener***

```
private class JsonObjectListener extends Response.SimpleObjectResponse {
    private Callback callback;
    public JsonObjectListener(Callback callBack){
         this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(int requestCode, @Nullable JSONObject jsonObject){
        callback.onResponse(jsonObject);
    }
 }
```

It's should work, tell if that resolve your probleme or not.

Comment: Hmm, it is still telling me that getJson is mission its return statement.

Comment: That's it just change `JsonObject` by `void`

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  I think I am just having one of those days.  Now in my main activity I am getting a debug error: `Non-static method getJson(....) cannot be referenced from a static context` when I call using `JSONHelper.getJson(this, url, new Callback(){
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject){
                    // Do what you want here
                }
            });`

Comment: Just add `static` before the void.

Comment: Now it is telling me the JsonObjectListener cannot be referenced from a static context.  Is the problem that I have it in a separate class from the main activity?

Comment: No, it's because of the `static`, you have two way to fix that, put `static` before `class` of JsonObjectListener, or add the JsonObjectListener as parameter in the `getJson()`